# How to clear a TextBox in MVVM?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a TextBox in a DataTemplate declared as follows:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,4,0,0">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.NotesEnteredCommand,
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
            <cmd:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SimpleMultiValueConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Row.OID" />
                    <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </cmd:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
        </cmd:EventToCommand>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<TextBox.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataContext.NotesEnteredCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
        <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SimpleMultiValueConverter}">
                <Binding Path="Row.OID" />
                <Binding Path="Text" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
    </KeyBinding>
</TextBox.InputBindings>
```

What this TextBox basically does is execute a MVVM-Light RelayCommand when the Enter key is pressed or when losing focus.

My problem is that I cannot figure out a way in MVVM to clear the TextBox's **Text** value through XAML in the above two scenarios. It's very easy with in code-behind, but I can't figure it out in MVVM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a binding for the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to a property in the ViewModel, Set the property to "" and your `TextBox` text will get cleared?

Comment: I can't have it in the ViewModel, my rows are bound to a DataView which would require me to have a column just for this purpose. But thanks for the reply  :)

Comment: @user2170838 Don't forget you can use something like a `RelativeSource` binding to bind to something other than the current DataContext, such as `Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.NewNoteText}"`, where the `DataContext` of your `DataGrid` holds both the `DataView`and a string property for the new note text. Of course, this only works if the Text is static regardless of which row is clicked on :)

Comment: I thought of that, but the Text is not static and depends on each row.  :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the text is part of your data layer and application logic, a string should exist in your `Model` or `ViewModel` and be cleared from there

For example,

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewNote}" ... />
```

and

```
void NotesEntered(int oid)
{
    SaveNewNote(oid);

    NewNote = string.Empty;
}
```

If it's part of the UI layer only, it should just be cleared with code-behind. It's perfectly acceptable to have UI-specific logic in the code-behind the UI, as that still maintains the separation of layers.

```
NewNoteTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
}

NewNoteTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Keys.Enter)
        (sender as TextBox).Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I was worried that using code-behind would defeat the purpose of MVVM, but you're right it doesn't interact with the ViewModel so it should be perfectly fine   :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UpdateSourceHelper. This really helped me out calling an event with no code-behind.
See here http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/1701

All you have to do is create a class "UpdateSourceHelper", connect it with your xaml like this

```
xmlns:local="using:WiredPrairie.Converter
```

and bind it to your TextBox (or whatever you want to bind to)...

```
<TextBox Height="Auto" Margin="0,6" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" TabIndex="0" 
     Text="{Binding Value}" 
     local:UpdateSourceHelper.IsEnabled="True" 
     local:UpdateSourceHelper.UpdateSourceText="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

If you want call LostFocus Event in the Helper, you simply have to add these 2 lines in your Helper:

```
tb.LostFocus += AttachedTextBoxLostFocus;
tb.LostFocus -= AttachedTextBoxLostFocus;
```

So it would look like this:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)obj;
    if ((bool)args.NewValue)
        {                           
            tb.LostFocus += AttachedTextBoxLostFocus;
        }
    else
        {
            tb.LostFocus -= AttachedTextBoxLostFocus;
        }
```

Right click on AttachedTextBoxLostFocus and generate the method. Now you can handle the Event like a code-behind event.