# Clearing textboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, textbox

I'm making an input page and I'm trying to implement a reset button. After a click on the button, the UI should be empty again.

I thought that entering an empty string would deal with this. In the code it seems to work and the value does get changed to "" but in the UI the typed text stays visible (so it doesn't show the empty "" string). I also tried with string.Empty as suggested in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196466/how-to-clear-a-textbox-in-mvvm) but that also doesn't seem to work.

Am I missing something here? I'm kinda new to programming so if I did something horribly wrong, don't laugh too hard ;)

I'm using an MVVM pattern and Fody Weaver to deal with the property changed part of the code.

**The UI / XAML**

```
<TextBlock Text="Naam:"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Style="{StaticResource InputInputBlock}"
           />

<TextBox Foreground="White"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Style="{StaticResource InputInputBox}"
         />

<Button Content="Reset"
            Height="50"
            Width="150"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="2"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Style="{StaticResource FlatButton}"
            Command="{Binding ResetCommand}"
            />
```

**The view model**

```
private string _name;
public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set
            {
                _name = value;
            }
        }
public AddStakeholderViewModel()
        {
            ResetCommand = new RelayCommand(() => ResetForm());
        }

private void ResetForm()
        {
            Name = " ";
        }
```

Comment: Try String.Empty. Ideally the txtBoxControl.Clear() should 
 do the trick. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.clear(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: you don't have notification in Name setter and UI doesn't see change in view model after invoking command. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raise event in setter

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava, I tried String.Empty but that doesn't seem to do anything. The txtBoxControl.Clear() can't be used in an MVVM patter, can it? If so, could you elaborate more?

Comment: @ASh I indeed forgot to implement my BaseViewModel interface. Thanks for pointing it out! If you post it as a solution, we can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your class. This works for me:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        // Declare the event
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
<TextBox Foreground="White"
     Grid.Column="1"
     Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
     Style="{StaticResource InputInputBox}"
     />
```

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = newPerson;
    }
    Person newPerson = new Person();
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        newPerson.Name = "";
    }
}
```